# Retrieving key array from Firebase, "variable used within its own value"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase structure]

Trying to get an array of child keys from Firebase

```
func getWavePosts() {
    let wavePostRoot = Database.database().reference().child("waves_posts/\(self.waveLabel!)/")

    wavePostRoot.observe(.value , with: {snapshot in

        var tempKeys = [String]()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key {
                 tempKeys.append(key as String)
            }
        }
        self.tempNames = tempKeys
})
}
```

I've done this for values before but not keys, the append line is the one that is flagged. Inserting a line below the key initialization changes the error to "Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred". Any help would be much appreciated!

--------- edit without for loop ---------

```
 let wavePostRoot = Database.database().reference().child("waves_posts/\(self.waveLabel!)/")

    wavePostRoot.observe(.value , with: {snapshot in

        var tempKeys = [String]()

        self.tempNames.append(snapshot.key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do optional-binding but you forgot to `if` keyword. Also I think that you want to check if `snap.key` is of type `String`

```
if let string = snap.key as? String {
    tempKeys.append(string)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it cleared up the error! Still returning an empty array though...added a pic of the Firebase structure to the OP if that helps

Comment: Nope still returns an empty array

Comment: I think I understood you, added the new edit to be sure

Comment: Hey. It wasn't returning a specific error just an empty array, but I figured out it was an order in the call hierarchy not with the for loop itself. The answer with the for loop is correct btw, to return the child keys instead of the parent key. Thanks for the help!